# Force deletion of userdata on update

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I rewrote most of my apps code so that it uses another system to write the files. In order to prevent bugs/confusion/crashes I'd like to force the user to clear the previously saved app data before installing the update. Is there an easy way to do this? Maybe something that gets called only the first time the app is started?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement this in your new version

Github: https://github.com/ihrupin/samples/tree/master/android/Clear_User_Data_Sample

Code:

```
package com.hrupin.cleaner;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }
        package com.hrupin.cleaner;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if(appDir.exists()){
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for(String s : children){
                if(!s.equals("lib")){
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Log.i("TAG", "File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s +" DELETED");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
}
    public static MyApplication getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if(appDir.exists()){
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for(String s : children){
                if(!s.equals("lib")){
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Log.i("TAG", "File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s +" DELETED");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

Reference: http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically

Comment: But wouldn't this delete the userdata every time? How do I get it to only run once on installation (or first start) of the app?

Comment: You can store your last version on SharedPreferences and check onStart, if different from the actual version you can call the terminator and destroy everything  :)